# How to clear memory from matplotlib - pyplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to remove the unneeded memory in an app I've made using tkinter. Every time a certain button is pressed, it shows a graph using matplotlib

This is my code

```
def DisplayData(DateRange):
    data = DBhandle.DBextract(DateRange)
    plt.close("all")
    SMALL_SIZE = 8
    MEDIUM_SIZE = 10
    BIGGER_SIZE = 12
    plt.rc('font', size=SMALL_SIZE)        
    plt.rc('axes', titlesize=SMALL_SIZE)   
    plt.rc('axes', labelsize=MEDIUM_SIZE)  
    plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)  
    plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)  
    plt.rc('legend', fontsize=SMALL_SIZE)  
    plt.rc('figure', titlesize=BIGGER_SIZE)
    plt.bar(data.keys(), data.values())    
    plt.tight_layout()                      
    plt.suptitle(DateRange, x=0.5, y=0.97) 
    plt.show()
```

I have tried this

```
plt.clf()
plt.cla()
f = plt.figure() 
f.clear() 
plt.close(f)
plt.close('all')
matplotlib.pyplot.figure().clear() 
matplotlib.pyplot.close()
pylhelp.Gcf().destroy_all()
```

Nothing is working. The memory usage just increases every time the function is used